# Not Seeing MDC Properties in logs

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have a simple program as shown below

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

    public class SLF4JMDC {
      private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SLF4JMDC.class);
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        MDC.put("user", "rafal.kuc@sematext.com");
        LOGGER.info("This is an info level log message!");
        LOGGER.warn("This is an WARN level log");
      }
    }
```

When I ran this program the output is just

This is an info level log message!
This is an WARN level log

**Its not showing up MDC Properties in logs**

Comment: What is your logger configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your logger to print MDC data. If you are using logback, it can be done with

```xml
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
  <layout>
    <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg User : %X{user}%m%n</Pattern>
  </layout> 
</appender>
```

`%x{user}` specifies logback to append it from MDC.

Reference : [Chapter 8: Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

Answer (score -1):

The less important logs would be ignored. For commonly used logging levels (`ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO`, `DEBUG`, and `TRACE`, etc). Their precedence are:

`Trace` < `Debug` < `Info` < `Warn` < `Error` < `Fatal`.

So You need to change the log level to `Warn` or less to be able to catch the message. You can change the level either by customizing the configuration **or** simply calling relative API in code ahead.

- code method example:

  ```
  Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
  root.setLevel(Level.WARN);
  ```
- configuration example: find the configuration file name `simplelogger.properties` and modify it accordingly.

  ```
  org.slf4j.Logger.defaultLogLevel=warn
  ```